# Listview item is not clickable

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I have listview. i am populating it with Adapter but it is not clickable. i have check listview is not null. 
I have Listview Population code in Activity
It is filled by DemoAdapter using Another view.

Here is Code Of Activity

```
 var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.menuListRestaurent);
        DemoAdapter adapter = new DemoAdapter(this, mItems);
        listView.Adapter = new DemoAdapter(this, mItems);
        listView.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var t = mItems[e.Position];
            int id = t.ProductId;
            var activity2 = new Intent(this, typeof(SingleProductDetailActivity));
            activity2.PutExtra("MyData", id);
            StartActivity(activity2);
        };
```

Here is Listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/menuListRestaurent" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/lightgray">
  <ScrollView
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#ff81d4fa">
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/Icon"
          android:layout_width="48dp"
          android:layout_height="48dp"
          android:src="@drawable/icon" />
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingLeft="10dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />
      </LinearLayout>
    </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Demo Adpater

```
{
    public class DemoAdapter : BaseAdapter<ProductModel>
    {
        public List<ProductModel> mItems;
        private Context mContext;

        public DemoAdapter(Context context, List<ProductModel> items)
        {
            mContext = context;
            mItems = items;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return mItems.Count;
            }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override ProductModel this[int position]
        {
            get
            {
                return mItems[position];
            }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            //var view = mContext.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ImageAndSubTitle, null);
            //var item = GetItem(position); 
            //view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Item1;
            //view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.Item2;
            //view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Icon).SetImageResource(item.Item3);
            //view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Clickable = true;
            //return view;

            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ImageAndSubTitle, null, false);
            }

            TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1);
            txtName.Text = mItems[position].ProductName;

            TextView txtPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2);
            txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(mItems[position].ProductPrice);

            //ImageView imgFood = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Icon);
            //imgFood.SetImageResource(Resource.Id.Icon);
            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What represents the second XML you posted? Can you post the code of the `DemoAdapter`?

Comment: If you are take click event from your adater view(Parent view) the item click not working

Comment: Moreover, you need to switch to RecyclerView ...

Comment: @apineda Check i have update demoadpater

Comment: @DevKriya this is just a wild guest => remove the `ScrollView` from the second XML which I imagine is the ListView Item layout. Anyway you don't need it as this might be blocking the click event from the Item.

Comment: That ScrollView may block clicks. remove it and try again. or set android:clickable="false"

Comment: @DevKriya curious if this finally worked..

Comment: Agree that your item view may block the click event.

Comment: @apineda You right scroll view is blocking click.! but without scroll listview is none of use! :(

Answer (score 1):

```
  ListView listview= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingListViewId);
        final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(mItems,getApplicationContext());
        listview.setAdapter(listview);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {




}
    });
```

Comment: i am using xamarin